# How to use common class url for all component in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have one common-class and this common class is imported in all components and this common class url is used in all component but this commonUrl is not works so how to make commonUrl for all component in angular (because in future i have to make change only in common-class for commonUrl) ?

```
export class CommonClass {
  constructor(commonUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000'){}
}
```

category.component.html

```
<button mat-button><img src="commonUrl/{{categoryObj.categoryimage}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;"/></button>
```

follow.component.html

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
   <img src="commonUrl/{{element.userimage}}" style="height: 40px;width: 40px;"/>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to import class in your component and then create a instance of that class use in view

here's an example

in `.ts`

```
import {CommonClass} from ../yourfolder/commomurl

commonClassObj: CommonClass = new CommonClass();
```

and in `.html`

```
<button mat-button><img src="{{commonClassObj.commonUrl}}/{{categoryObj.categoryimage}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;"/></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the file in the folder `environnements`.

[image]

In the file `environnement.dev.ts` :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
};
```

Consuming environnement variables :

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

In your component :

```
apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a static variable to access a common url

```
export class CommonClass {
  public static commonUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000'
}
```

in category.component.ts access the property

```
categoryimage = CommonClass.commonUrl 

<button mat-button><img src="commonUrl/{{categoryimage}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;"/></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.module.ts` file add provider for your url. Your code should look like this

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ...........
    ],
    providers: [
        ........
        //use this line   
        { provide: 'API_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:3000' },
    ]
})
```

and at your component you have to inject that

```
export class YourComponent {
    apiUrl: string;

    constructor(@Inject('API_URL') apiUrl: string) {
        this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
    }
}
```

and now you can use that url anywhere in your component

Answer (score 0):

another approach if nothing works: use OUTPUT to emit the value

```
 @Output() commonUrl : EventEmitter<Boolean> = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
```

emit it at the main class where you defined commonurl

```
this.commonUrl.emit(goToAccountView);
```

and use @Input() in components you want to use this commonURL.

Hope It helps